# PCI - Store Cryptographic Keys Securely, Requirement 3.4

Tags: encryption, e-commerce, pci-dss, pci-compliance

From the PCI DSS2 docs:
https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/pci_dss_v2.pdf

3.4.1.b Verify that cryptographic keys are stored securely (for 
example, stored on removable media that is adequately protected 
with strong access controls).

We're using a batch-processing fulfillment house that handles credit card data once every 24 hours. This requires we store customer credit card data for as long as a week worst-case if there's an outage, etc.

During this time we'd like the CC info stored to be stored as securely as possible. I've seen setups where the data is stored encrypted with the key stored on a thumb drive that's attached nightly to run the batch process, but this is an incredibly flimsy and manual method of handling the batch process. Surely there's a better way to store the key, but protect it from hackers who get access to the machine, or exploit software installed on the machine.

What's the best way to store a key without this manual process?

Comment: You might want to ask over on http://security.stackexchange.com. See http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1412/pci-encryption-key-management, for example.

Comment: Ah, did not realize there was a whole additional branch of Stackoverflow (it's too bad searching here doesn't include results from there...). If an admin wants to close this thread as a dupe that works for me.

Comment: One of the bests ways of protecting a (private) key is to put it off-line. Problem with storing it on the server is that you need to encrypt it to store it securily. Then you have the problem of storing the key to decrypt the stored key. This you can encrypt... you'll probably understand what I'm heading for. I'm however seriously worried that anybody who is supposed to protect large numbers of credit card numbers to ask starter questions on key management. Hire a consultant, for pity's sake.